# How can I find the minimum and maximum value within a decimal list?

Tags: c#

I have created a list type decimal. I'm creating a method that does a couple simple analytics tasks. How do I find and display the minimum and maximum value within the list.

I haven't tried anything because I can't find the syntax.

```
static void Analytics()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1 Display student grade average");
            Console.WriteLine("2 Display Lowest grade + Student Name");
            Console.WriteLine("3 Display Highest grade +Student Name");

            Console.Write("Option: ");

            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            decimal average;
            if (choice == "1")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                decimal gradeSum = 0m;

                Console.WriteLine("Grades Analytics");

                for (int count = 0; count < firstName.Count; count++)
                {
                    gradeSum += studentGrade[count];
                }

                average = (gradeSum / studentGrade.Count) * .01m;

                Console.Write("Average Grade: ");
                Console.WriteLine(average.ToString("p2"));

            }
            else if (choice == "2")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                //display min here

            }
            else if (choice == "3")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                //display max here

            }
        }
```

You'll see the place I'm trying to write the code on choice # 2 & 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `System.linq`. With LINQ, you can have an expression like: `studentGrade.Min(x => x.grade)` to get the minimum grade, and `studentGrade.Max(x => x.grade)` to get the maximum. Give that a try.

I highly recommend looking more into LINQ as a C# developer. It is in my opinion, one of the best tools available to C# developers.

Comment: @mitchhaley: If you are learning,  it's worth doing this by hand. Start by assigning a minValue (to a very large number) and a maxValue (to a very small value). Then iterate over the collection (once), comparing the current value to the min and max values, setting a new min or max value as appropriate. This is something you will likely do many times in your life. And, as an added bonus, it's faster than the Linq solution (since it only iterates over the collection once, not twice like the Linq solution)